# Should this bunch of typedefs be private or public?

Tags: c++, class, graph, typedef

I'm writing a class that represents a graph, so I've wrote the following header

```
class Graph {
public:
  Graph(); 
  Graph(int N);

  void addVertex();
  void addEdge(VertexNum v1, VertexNum v2, Weight w);


  std::pair<PathLength, Path> shortestPath
    (const VerticesGroup& V1, const VerticesGroup& V2);


private:
  typedef int                           VertexNum;
  typedef int                           Weight;
  typedef std::pair<VertexNum, Weight>  Edge;
  typedef std::vector<Edge>             Path;
  typedef size_t                        PathLength;
  typedef std::vector<VertexNum>        VerticesGroup;


  std::vector<std::list<Edge> > adjList;

  bool incorrectVertexNumber(VertexNum v);
};
```

I have some questions about the above code:

1. Should I declare the bunch of typedefs public or private?
2. Is it a normal practice, when one typedefs one type to different synonyms (like typedef int VertexNum; typedef int Weight;)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.
Access control in C++ is applied purely to names. There's a note and example in ISO/IEC 14882:2011 11 [class.access]/4 that makes it clear that this is the intention.

`[...] [ Note: Because access control applies to names, if access control is applied to a typedef name, only the accessibility of the typedef name itself is considered. The accessibility of the entity referred to by the typedef is not considered. For example,`

```
class A {
  class B { };
public:
  typedef B BB;
};

void f() {
   A::BB x; // OK, typedef name A::BB is public
  A::B y; // access error, A::B is private
}
—end note ]
```

2.
it is ok, as you can make some type meaningful and easily understandable.

Answer (score 9):

Any `typedef` used in the `public` interface of the class should be in the `public` section of the class. Rest should be `private`.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you declare as `private`, you will not be able to use them outside your class. I guess this is not what you want, specially if the `typedef`ed name appears as parameter type in your public interface. If you restrict using the `typedef`ed name within your class, then make it `private`.
2. It is certainly common practice to rename a type using `typedef` to a more usable/easily understandable name at the domain level.